# How to use the value of a register in a key mapping?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, bash

I want  to map a key to the system command

```
`tmux set-buffer $var`
```

where $var is the value of @0 register. 
How do i insert the @0 value into the map command

```
map <leader>t :!tmux set-buffer @0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `:execute {expr1}` to execute a string from evaluation of `{expr1}` as an Ex command.

```
:exec "!tmux set-buffer" getreg("0")
```

will first combine the string `!tmux set-buffer` with the results of `getreg("0")`, adding a space in between, and then execute the resulting command. Presumably you want this only in normal mode, so it is advisable to use `nnoremap` instead of `map` as well.

The mapping itself should be

```
nnoremap <leader>t :exec "!tmux set-buffer" getreg("0")<CR>
```

Comment: You can also just use `@0` instead of the `getreg()` function.